# Extending external classes

Tags: typescript

How can I add additional properties to an existing typed object without making the compiler complain?  For instance, if I want to add an additional FindByEmail method on an instance of a Mongoose model.  The solution below is the only way I could find to satisfy the compiler.  Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve this?

```
    export var userSchema = new Schema({
        name: String, email: String
    });

    export interface IUser extends Document {
        name: string; email: string;
    }

    interface IMyUser extends Model<IUser> {
        FindByEmail(target: string): mongoose.Query<IUser>;
    }

    interface IMyUser extends Model<IUser> {
    FindByEmail(target: string): Query<IUser>;
}

function Create(user: Model<IUser>) {

    (<IMyUser>user).FindByEmail = (target: string) => {
        return user.findOne({ email: target })
    }
    return <IMyUser>this.user;
}

export var User = Create(_db.model<IUser>("User", userSchema));

    User.create({name:"canIbeFound", email:"a@b.com"});

    //User.FindByEmail("a@b.com").exec().then((res) => {
    //     if (res) {
    //         console.log(res.email + " was found belonging to " + res.name)
    //     }
    // })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module augmentation is supported from TypeScript v1.8 and allows you to write ambient definitions to extend global and module scope.

This is not allowed in earlier versions.

```
declare module "mongoose" {
     FindByEmail: (target: string) => IMyUser;
}
```